# How do I manually shape this heating element?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have here a heating element that broke when it was used to ramp a furnace to 750 C, breaking at 740. The element had previously been used for higher temperatures and appears that it may have possibly shorted. The shape of the element is custom, as well as the furnace, and so we had a custom element machined with a specific wind, but this new element is straight. I have few tools and am limited in buying tools; So, whats the best way I can give the coil this shape? Some things to consider:

- The previous coil broke at what appears to be a weak point. It's possible that it shorted, but its also possible that it just gave out. Therefore, with shaping it, there needs to be as few of strained points as possible.
- It needs to remain planar, which is our largest problem right now. I attempted to curl it around a cylinder, and it now spirals upward (we have more coil if we need to start over.) If it doesn't remain planar, shorting will be likely.
- When we attempted to spiral around a cylinder, it gives a good general shape, but will generally expand after releasing tension.

Below are two photos of what we are dealing with. The poorly coiled lustrous one is the new, and the burnt black piece in the ceramic is the old.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wasn't sure which SE site to post this to. If this is way out of the scope of the site, then my apologies.

Comment: Why aren't you using the ceramic form to make the shape?

Comment: There's little mechanical strength and we're afraid of breaking it. Previous ones have broke.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT** Just read the comments, #3 might be the best option, as #1 won't work, and #2 wont shape it, just hold it in place.

First thing I am assuming is that this stays in the ceramic as it is heated.

A couple things I would try:

1. Fit the coil in the ceramic like the bottom picture is, but with the new coil, then put something heavy on top and let it sit there for a long while.  Hopefully that would work, but no promises.
2. Find a thin, non-conducting material that can withstand at least twice the temperature that it will be subjected to (Possibly even more ceramic), and put a plus shape over the heating element to hold it in place.
3. Bend the coil bit by bit to get it to stay in the right shape.  start by bending it to where it should be, then releasing it.  If it does not stay, bend it past the point you want it at.  Keep bending it farther until it stays in the place you want it.  You may need to do very small sections at a time, so this will take a very long time.  Unfortunately, this may cause a little weakness in the metal.
4. Carve a wood shape that matches the ceramic and use that to form the spring using method 1

Good Luck, I hope you can get something to work!

Comment: Hi Mason, welcome to engineering.SE!  For answers, there is no need to explicitly show where you have edited the post.  If you've realized a way to improve your answer, you should simply incorporate the edit into the answer.  This makes it more cohesive for future visitors who don't want to try and understand the entire history of the question and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Classic engineer behavior, not answering the question that was asked. These are instructions for making the coil, not getting it into the shape you want. Sorry.

I had to do something like this for my senior design project. After determining the characteristics of the coil (length, diameter, and pitch) I used a lathe to fashion an appropriately sized threaded rod. I drilled a hole through the rod near the top of the threads large enough to accommodate the resistive wire that I was winding the heating element out of. I installed this jig in a lathe with the aforementioned hole close to the chuck and I turned the rotational speed of the lathe way down.

I fed the end of resistive wire, which was on a spool, through the aforementioned hole to secure the wire allowing it to wind. As I turned on the lathe I maintained constant tension on the wire as it wound around the threaded rod. After winding a sufficient length I (turned off the lathe and) clipped the end near the hole and removed the bit that was securing the wire to the . After releasing the tension from the wire it relaxed a little and slipped off the threaded shaft quite easily! If your wire doesn't relax as much then you might have to 'unscrew' it from the shaft, but it should come off. After that I did some finishing operations on the freshly-minted coil. I was able to produce several near-perfect coils using this technique!